# Create a percentage preloader with words instead of number?

Tags: javascript, percentage, preloader

I am trying to create a percentage preloader that has words instead of numbers....  i.e. ONE PERCENT, TWO PERCENT, etc. up to ONE HUNDRED PERCENT.

I know it will move very fast...

Not quite sure where to even start?   Have googled and tried my hand at a bit, just a push in the right direction is all I'm looking for!

Thx!!!

Comment: Do you have a way to convert numbers into strings?

Comment: not sure?  sorry i'm a bit of a javascript newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function I'm going to use to convert a number below 100 to the english version:

```
function numberToString(n) {

    var toFifteen = "ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE,TEN,ELEVEN,TWELVE,THIRTEEN,FOURTEEN,FIFTEEN".split(",");
    var tens = "TEEN,TWENTY,THIRTEE,FOURTY,FIFTY,SIXTY,SEVENTY,EIGHTY,NINETY".split(",");
    if (n == 0)
        return "ZERO";
    if (n <= 15)
        return toFifteen[n - 1];
    if (n < 20)
        return (toFifteen[- -(n+"")[1] - 1] || "") + "TEEN";
    if (n == 100)
        return "ONE HUNDRED";
     return tens[- -(n+"")[0] - 1] + " " + (toFifteen[- -(n+"")[1] - 1] || "");
}
```

I provide 2 approach, the first works if you only want one or you use arrays, the second works if you want multiple ones and you want to manage them easily.

First approach:

```js
// Create progress bar element
var progress = document.createElement("span");
var currProgress = 0;

progress.innerHTML = numberToString(currProgress)

// You should put the el
document.body.appendChild(progress);

// This following part updates the progress bar, change this
// to whatever way you want it to get updated

setInterval(function() {
  currProgress++;
  if (currProgress > 100)
    currProgress = 0;
  progress.innerHTML = numberToString(currProgress);
}, 100);

function numberToString(n) {
    
    var toFifteen = "ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE,TEN,ELEVEN,TWELVE,THIRTEEN,FOURTEEN,FIFTEEN".split(",");
    var tens = "TEEN,TWENTY,THIRTEE,FOURTY,FIFTY,SIXTY,SEVENTY,EIGHTY,NINETY".split(",");
    if (n == 0)
        return "ZERO";
    if (n <= 15)
        return toFifteen[n - 1];
    if (n < 20)
        return (toFifteen[- -(n+"")[1] - 1] || "") + "TEEN";
    if (n == 100)
        return "ONE HUNDRED";
     return tens[- -(n+"")[0] - 1] + " " + (toFifteen[- -(n+"")[1] - 1] || "");
}
```

This allows you to have 1 progress bar on the page, but I'd recommend using a more object oriented solution:

```js
function ProgressBar(startingProgress) {
  // This makes the argument optional
  // If the user doesn't enter a number, then it will
  // default to 0
  if (!startingProgress)
    startingProgress = 0;
  this.progress = 0;
  
  this.element = document.createElement("span");
  this.element.innerHTML = ProgressBar.numberToString(this.progress);
}

ProgressBar.prototype.step = function(amount) {
  // Same as with startingProgress
  if (!amount)
    amount = 1;
  this.progress += amount;
  this.element.innerHTML = ProgressBar.numberToString(this.progress);
}

// "Static" method
ProgressBar.numberToString = function(n) {
    
    var toFifteen = "ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE,TEN,ELEVEN,TWELVE,THIRTEEN,FOURTEEN,FIFTEEN".split(",");
    var tens = "TEEN,TWENTY,THIRTEE,FOURTY,FIFTY,SIXTY,SEVENTY,EIGHTY,NINETY".split(",");
    if (n == 0)
        return "ZERO";
    if (n <= 15)
        return toFifteen[n - 1];
    if (n < 20)
        return (toFifteen[- -(n+"")[1] - 1] || "") + "TEEN";
    if (n == 100)
        return "ONE HUNDRED";
     return tens[- -(n+"")[0] - 1] + " " + (toFifteen[- -(n+"")[1] - 1] || "");
}

var progress = new ProgressBar();
document.body.appendChild(progress.element);

setInterval(function() {
    progress.step(1);
}, 100);
```

Comment: WOW thank you @Bálint !!!!   Now i just have to figure out how to do it in french hahaha.  thank you!

Comment: @user3176993 I think you will need to bruteforce that. French's numbering system is evil

Comment: @user3176993 How do you say 81? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391240/why-do-the-french-count-so-strangely

Comment: lol, yeah. @Bálint i just mean, is there i way i can define every single number?  I can write each one out, i just wouldn't know where..

Comment: You need to change the function a lot. It's optimized for english.